# conditionally define an variable in a Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have a tag in my Makefile as follows:

```
%.o: %.c
    CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(STACK_OPTS) $(SIO_FLAGS) $(IO_FLAGS) $(LOCAL_INCLUDES) $(OAK_FLAGS) -DSYNC_WRITE $(OAK_LIBS) $<
    $(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $(OAK_FLAGS) $(LOCAL_INCLUDES) $^ > $*.d
    @cp -f $*.d $*.d.tmp
    @sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < $*.d.tmp | fmt -1 | \
      sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> $*.d
    @rm -f $*.d.tmp
```

I need to CONDITIONALLY add another define variable for a group of .c source file and have it set ONLY for those ones.  Can that be done?  I presume it would be inserted after the CFLAGS= line.

Any ideas?  The var I want to define is FOO_OTO.  Just needs to be defined not set to any value.

Comment: Actually, the `CFLAGS` assignment does nothing at all.  Each line in a recipe is executed in its own subshell; thus, the shell assigns `CFLAGS` and exits, leaving the value unchanged in the parent.

Comment: As a workaround, could you add the assignment to `$*.d` for the files which need it?  (I am assuming this file contains dependency information for the target.)

Answer (score 2):

You can set variables on a per-target basis (assuming GNU make) using target-specific variables.  So if you have a list of source files in `FOO_SRC` and you want to add some extra flags to them, you can do something like this:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS =

FOO_SRC = foo.c bar.c baz.c

$(FOO_SRC:.c=.o): EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXTRA
```

Then add `$(EXTRA_CFLAGS)` to your compile rule.  By the way, it's useless to have `CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"` in your rule.  This does nothing (except cost you some performance).

Comment: thx.  I like this approach. I had found the gnu make manual and the section on target vars.  This is mucho cleaner.  danka. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable holding the names of the files you need like so:

```
FILES_WITH_FOO_OTO = foo.c bar.c
```

You can use the following construct:

```
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(if $(filter $<,$(FILES_WITH_FOO_OTO)), -DFOO_OTO)
```

This is a complete rewrite of my answer as I apparently misunderstood the qusetion.

Comment: You could use an indirection like `VAR_foo=-DFOO_OTO` and then for the target `foo.o` use `${VAR_$*}` which expands to `-DFOO_OTO`.  Similarly for every other target which needs it.